# Alternative to onActivityResult for startUpdateFlowForResult

Tags: android, android-studio, onactivityresult, in-app-update

What is the alternative to get callback for startUpdateFlowForResult in InAppUpdates instead of onActivityResult since it is deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

We have to wait for Google Play team to migrate away from the deprecated APIs. You can follow this issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181785653).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes-in_app_updates

Answer (score 3):

An updated Google doc has been made available:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java

You can launch the update like this:

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
    appUpdateInfo,
    // an activity result launcher registered via registerForActivityResult
    activityResultLauncher,
    // Or pass 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' to newBuilder() for
    // flexible updates.
    AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE).build()
)
```

And the `activityResultLauncher` is set up in your Activity like this:

```
private val activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
    val resultCode = result.resultCode
    when {
        resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            Log.v("MyActivity", "Update flow completed!")
        }
        resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
            Log.v("MyActivity", "User cancelled Update flow!")
        }
        else -> {
            Log.v("MyActivity", "Update flow failed with resultCode:$resultCode")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this result launcher

```
private val updateFlowResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Handle successful app update
        }
    }
```

After that try to launch your intent like this

```
 val starter =
        IntentSenderForResultStarter { intent, _, fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, _, _ ->
            val request = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent)
                .setFillInIntent(fillInIntent)
                .setFlags(flagsValues, flagsMask)
                .build()

            updateFlowResultLauncher.launch(request)
        }

    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
        appUpdateInfo,
        AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
        starter,
        requestCode,
    )
```

Give it a try!

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code snippet alternative of onActivityResult()
First Activity

**Step 1**

```
 private val openActivity =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        handleActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE, it)
    }
```

**Step 2**

```
openActivity.launch(
            Intent(this, YourClass::class.java).apply {
                  putExtra(ANY_KEY, data) // If any data you want to pass 
            }
        )
```

**Step 3**

```
 private fun handleActivityResult(requestCode: Int, result: ActivityResult?) {
        Timber.e("========***handleActivityResult==requestActivty==$requestCode====resultCode=========${result?.resultCode}")
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            when (result?.resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                val intent =   result.data // received any data from another avtivity
                }
                Activity.RESULT_CANCELED->{
                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**In second class**

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra(ANY_KEY, data)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
finish()
```

Comment: yes I know, this to use with startActivityForResult. But how to use it with startUpdateFlowForResult. Since it takes on 4 parameters with it. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager.html#startUpdateFlowForResult(com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo,%20int,%20android.app.Activity,%20int)

Comment: No updates from google play team yet for this as they are saying that it is in their roadmap already so we don't have other option available accept waiting